# putting controller action into thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

After reading [Running Rails jobs in background threads](https://www.agileplannerapp.com/blog/building-agile-planner/rails-background-jobs-in-threads) I tried to refactor an controller action that is basically rendering an report in a xml format and sends the report file to the user browser. Now the action runs c. 30 sec, so I thought this a good candidate for a background job. Hovewer, I have run into a problem: it seems I can't access the report erb template from within the new thread.

This is my first attempt with threads and I am not sure if I am able to accomplish my refactoring with the approach.

Simplified code of action before refactoring:

```
@orders = Order.onrange(range).includes(:logo => [:simulations, :pantones])
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml {
    orders_xml = render_to_string template: 'orders/bom'
    send_data orders_xml, filename: "BOM raport - #{range.to_s}.xml"
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already see this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html if not, please take a closer look.

From what you describe you can achieve your goal with:

- Make a first request, that will call a controller action to produce the report and use the callback 'after_perform' to update the view with the produced report.
- Split the reports from "asking the report" and "view the report". The first will enqueue the report generation and once it's ready will be available for user in a reports section.

I would prefer the second option if you plan the report generation time will increase or if it's unacceptable to have the user waiting 30 secs for a report. Other option could be to generate the report after you have the needed data, so when the user ask for it it's already generated. (just guessing because I don't know your application flow)

Comment: I didn't consider Active Job as my project is on RoR 4.0.12. Perhaps it is time to upgrade? I will have a look at this guide, thanks.